# matplotlib legend not showing correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I am trying to plot some data from a csv file. I used the Pandas to load the csv file. I am using `sns.lineplot()` to plot the lines. But one of the legend is always faulty. It shows a square around one of the legend.

```py
plt.figure(dpi=150)
lin1 = sns.lineplot(x = "Training time", y = "Relative L2 error", data=df[df["Activation"]=="tanh"])
lin2 = sns.lineplot(x = "Training time", y = "Relative L2 error", data=df[df["Activation"]=="silu"])
lin3 = sns.lineplot(x = "Training time", y = "Relative L2 error", data=df[df["Activation"]=="swish"])
plt.xlabel("Training time  (sec)")
plt.legend(("tanh", "silu", "swish"))
plt.yscale('log',base=10)
```

I used 3 different functions because there are more `Activations`. This is the resulting plot.

[image]

The plot is looking correct but the legend is creating problems. Here are versions of the plotting tools that I am using.

```py
Python 3.9.12
matplotlib                    3.6.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
seaborn                       0.12.1
```

I could not find the same issue on Internet. A kernel restart isn't helping. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Can you use `plt.plot(...)` instead of `seaborn`? By using `plt.plot(...)` you can set the legend with the arg `label`.

Comment: You could create everything in one go: `sns.lineplot(x="Training time", y="Relative L2 error", data=df, hue="Activation", hue_order=["tanh",  "silu",  "swish"])`.  Seaborn will only use the activation values from `hue_order` and automatically create an appropriate legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the label argument to the individual lineplots and then just call legend without any arguments:

```
plt.figure(dpi=150)
lin1 = sns.lineplot(x = "Training time", y = "Relative L2 error", data=df[df["Activation"]=="tanh"], label = 'tanh')
lin2 = sns.lineplot(x = "Training time", y = "Relative L2 error", data=df[df["Activation"]=="silu"], label = 'silu')
lin3 = sns.lineplot(x = "Training time", y = "Relative L2 error", data=df[df["Activation"]=="swish"], label = 'swish')
plt.xlabel("Training time  (sec)")
plt.legend()
plt.yscale('log',base=10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also plot all your lines with a single command by using `hue`:

```
sns.lineplot(x="Training time", y="Relative L2 error", data=df[df["Activation"].isin(["tanh", "silu", "swish"])], hue="Activation")
```

Edit: as @JohanC cleverly suggested, you could use `hue_order` to get a slightly more compact expression:

```py
sns.lineplot(x="Training time", y="Relative L2 error", data=df, hue="Activation", hue_order=["tanh", "silu", "swish"])
```

Comment: I didn't! Thanks for the suggestion! I was not familiar with `hue_order`. I went with a solution I was confident with since OP didn't provide sample data.... I'm adding your suggestion to my answer if you don't mind!